# /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 - Trying to do CICD for ios in azure pipelines

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build CI process for ios app in azure pipeline.
I'm using microsoft agent (macos-latest), for now, I can't change it.
The xcode task take to of time, and break the build because of time limitation (1 hour).
I try to follow this instructors to solve the problem: [Reduce Azure Pipelines Xcode Build Time by 80% Through CocoaPods Caching](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/reduce-azure-pipelines-xcode-build-time-by-80-through-cocoapods-caching-5c2de0f657df)

When I add the flag use_frameworks! I get this error:

```
> The following build commands failed:
> 
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ dSYMs
> /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/nanopb.build/Script-46EB2E00016410.sh
> (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
> 
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ dSYMs
> /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/libwebp.build/Script-46EB2E00016400.sh
> (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
> 
> (2 failures)
> 
> ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

(... instead of company name)

Do you hava an idea how to solve this errors?
Thanks.